# Get rails associations from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rails-console

I have a model in my Rails application - User. I want all the associations to be listed in rails console, along with the type of association(1-1, 1-many).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations
```

This will return an array of associations similar to this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x00000105575548 @macro=:has_many, @name=:posts, @options={}, @active_record=User(id: integer, login: string), @collection=false>
```

Sample code:

```
reflections = User.reflect_on_all_associations
reflections.each do |reflection|
  puts ":#{reflection.macro} => :#{reflection.name}"
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, it does not work on an instance of a model.  It works on the model class.  I actually want all the details from associated records, not the schema level.

Comment: Agree, We could use 

    reflections = User.reflect_on_all_associations
    reflections.map(&:name)

Answer (score 5):

Using the gem [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) you will be able to access the model, its columns and relationships. Include it in your `Gemfile`, then you run `bundle`. You can use the command `show-models` when you are in your pry console. and you will get the information about all your models.

You can also run `show-model (Model_Name)` to get information about a specific model

Answer (score 2):

Add this some where is under /lib. For example clone_deep.rb.

```
module CloneDeep
  def clone_deep
    kopy = clone
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.each do |association|
      next if association.macro == :belongs_to
      cloned_object = case association.macro
                        when :has_many
                          self.send(association.name).collect { |item| item.clone_deep }
                        when :has_one
                          self.send(association.name) && self.send(association.name).clone_deep
                        else
                          clone
                      end
      kopy.send("#{association.name}=", cloned_object)
    end
    return kopy
  end
end
```

Create new initializer under config/initializers/ folder. Inside this file paste

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, CloneDeep)
```

Now you be able to clone model with all it's has_one and hos_many associations.

```
cloned_person = person.clone_deep
cloned_person.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm a new user, I am unable to clarify/reply to other's posts. I'll note that you need to reload the rails console before checking any changes in associations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for any particular :- 
user = User.reflect_on_association(:user_profile)
and
user.macro